# How to get the objectId of inserted row in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Well, i am trying to add a new row in a table in parse.com and get the objectID back. I don't think there is any method which will return back the ID just after inserting a row. So, i first inserted the row and tried to fetch the ID by using where condition. But it's not working- can't find the row in the table while query for fetching ID; its returning null object. But i can see the row in the table if i browse the table.

Below is the code. Here i used two method one to insert new row another for fetching ID. The codes are inside a button's click view event.

```
public void clkLogin(View v)
 {
        String user = txtUser.getText().toString();
        String pas = txtPass.getText().toString();

        saveUserToCloud(user , pas);
        getCloudId(user , pas);
}

private void saveUserToCloud(String us,String ps)
{
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("tblxxx");
        testObject.put("userName", us);
        testObject.put("password", ps);
    testObject.saveInBackground();
}


private void getCloudId(final String user,final String pasw)
 {
    Toast.makeText(this, user +"|" + pasw, 2000).show();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("tblxxx");
      query.whereEqualTo("userName", user);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
      {
        if (object == null)
        {
            Log.d("scoren", "not found");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.d("scoren", "--found");
            String myIdInCLoud =  object.getObjectId().toString();
        }
      }
    });

}
```

What can be the possible reason for it not working? Plus, is there any other way to get the ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your, `testObject.saveInBackground();` with

```
testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
       if(e==null){
           //saved successfully
           getCloudId(user , pas);
       }

    }
});
```

The above will ensure that you are only fetching for the **objectId** after the row has been saved on Parse.

Hope this works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
object.id
```

rather than

```
object.getObjectId().toString{};
```

myObj.id will allow you to retrieve object id

Answer (score 0):

If you use the version of `saveInBackground()` where you have a call-back, you will get the updated version of the object that includes the new object ID.

You can then save it somewhere to use later or just use it there as needed.

Also note that your code as it currently runs has a race condition between two "in background" operations... if for any reason the `saveInBackground()` is delayed, the `getFirstInBackground()` may run and gather data before it finishes, returning unexpected results.

You constantly need to be aware of the issues with async code.

Comment: :Thanks. That's why when i was using a handler thread and set the delayed time to 3 seconds-when calling the getCloudId() method , it was working. And sorry cant really up vote bcoz of low reputation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Object(in this case the ID and pwd) and retrieve the objectId from parse using a method called **done**.

```
private void saveUserToCloud(String us,String ps)
{
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("tblxxx");
    testObject.put("userName", us);
    testObject.put("password", ps);
    testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Success!
                String objectId = testObject.getObjectId();
            } else {
                // Failure!

            }
        });
        }
}
```

You can retrieve the list of Objects using the following method,

```
final ParseQuery<Object> query= new ParseQuery<>("abcd");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Object>()
{
    @Override
    public void done ( final List<Object> listResult, ParseException e){
    if (e == null) {
        // listResult returns all Rows from TableName = "abcd"
    } 
    else {
        //failure
    }
}
});
}
```